# Restricting automatic ListView grow

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I have a huge `XAML` in which a `ListView` automatically grows when new item is added, despite my tries to restrict its `MaxHeight`. Unfortunately, for some unknown reason, I cannot repeat undesirable behavior with simple `XAML`. Trying to deal with it several days already, but in vain. Basically I have:

```
<Border x:Name="BorderControl">
   <DockPanel x:Name="DockPanelControl">
      <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelControl">
          <!-- items here -->
      </StackPanel>
      <ListView MaxHeight={Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DockPanelControl} ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
      </ListView>
   </DockPanel>
</Border>
```

I tried to bind to `StackPanel, DockPanel, Border` 's `ActualHeight`, but just does not work - `ListView` keeps growing. Any suggestions, why this could be the case?

Comment: What happens if you put a hardcoded value for MaxHeight, does it work ?

Comment: @Adrian, yep, works as a charm, if the value is hardcoded.

Comment: What is the actual parent of the ListView?

Comment: @bit, DockPanel as is stated in the example above. No special attributes defined for it, just Background. ListView has no other attributes defined, except Margin, Background, BorderBrush and BorderThickness.

Comment: Try to encapsulate the DockPanel within a Grid with RowHeight=*,. I think that the default height here is Auto, which imlpies that occupy all the height you want to the DockPanel and hence the ListView. Restrict that to *, would make it occupy only the available height.

Comment: @bit, nope, did not work. I put **<RowDefinition Height="*" />** and it doesn't work. I have to add, that in StackPanel items can be added dynamically, though the ListView keeps growing even no items were added.

Comment: @Gabrielius You can use tools like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to investigate the controls while the app is running. That could be useful in this kind of situation.

Comment: IN case the stackpanel also grows in size, can you try to add a ScrollViewer around it? Along with the Grid with row height * of course.

Comment: @bit, that's not a desired outcome. I want StackPanel to grow in size and that ListView MaxHeight be automatically defined by StackPanel's (or its parent - DockPanel's) height and that ListView did not outgrow StackPanel. I will try to Snoop, as suggested by Adrian.